# hive script shell error

Tags: shell, hive, hiveql

I want to use shell script to execute some hive queries.
This is how my script shell look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
DST_ARCHIVE_TABLE=as400_nat_pp09_siedta_raw_dev.natart_archive
SRC_TABLE_HIVE=as400_nat_pp09_siedta_raw_dev.natart_to_process 
current_date=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
hive -e 'SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true; SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict; insert into table ${DST_ARCHIVE_TABLE} partition (to_porcess_ts) select * from ${SRC_TABLE_HIVE} where to_porcess_ts < ${current_date} '
```

But got this error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:19 cannot recognize input near 'table' '$' '{' in table name
```

I deleted the `{` but i still have the same error

Comment: did you try to write `insert into table` in uppercase?

Comment: i use the arguments in my querie and it works fine, @Carole yes upper and lowercase

Answer (score 1):

Hi try it like below:-

```
echo "SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true; SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict; insert into table ${DST_ARCHIVE_TABLE} partition (to_porcess_ts) select * from ${SRC_TABLE_HIVE} where to_porcess_ts < ${current_date}" | hive -e
```

or

```
echo "SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true; SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict; insert into table ${DST_ARCHIVE_TABLE} partition (to_porcess_ts) select * from ${SRC_TABLE_HIVE} where to_porcess_ts < ${current_date} - e" | hive
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below approach by using `hiveconf` (showing with an example):

1) Move your Hive query into a .hql file. Parameters will be indicated via `hiveconf`.

```
-- query.hql
select * from ${hiveconf:MY_DB}.${hiveconf:MY_TABLE} limit 1
```

2) Make a shell script to set parameter values for the query, and to execute it.

```
-- query.sh

#!/bin/bash
hive -hiveconf MY_DB=default -hiveconf MY_TABLE=my_hive_table_name -f query.hql
```

3) Execute it

```
./query.sh
```